# How to safely convert from a double to a decimal in c#

Tags: c#

We are storing financial data in a SQL Server database using the decimal data type and we need 6-8 digits of precision in the decimal.  When we get this value back through our data access layer into our C# server, it is coming back as the decimal data type.

Due to some design constraints that are beyond my control, this needs to be converted.  Converting to a string isn't a problem.  Converting to a double is as the MS documentation says "[converting from decimal to double] can produce round-off errors because a double-precision floating-point number has fewer significant digits than a decimal."

As the double (or string) we can round to 2 decimal places after any calculations are done, so what is the "right" way to do the decimal conversion to ensure that we don't lose any precision before the rounding?

Comment: According to MSDN, decimal has a precision of 28-29 digits and double has 15-16. But if you're only storing 6-8 digits, then I would think that round-off wouldn't affect you. This could be easily unit tested to see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The conversion won't produce errors within the first 8 digits. `double` has 15-16 digits of precision - less than the 28-29 of `decimal`, but enough for your purposes by the sounds of it.

You should definitely put in place some sort of plan to avoid using `double` in the future, however - it's an unsuitable datatype for financial calculations.

Comment: Beat my comment by 15 secs! (+1) :)

Comment: *"it's an unsuitable datatype for financial calculations."* Would you elaborate on this, at your leisure? It's one of those things I've always "known" and not necessarily understood. Cheers! :)

Comment: @djacobson: Financial calculations are typically *expressed* in decimals - one expects that the result of adding (say) 0.01 and 0.01 is *exactly* 0.02. That's trick in `double` where neither 0.01 nor 0.02 can be represented exactly. Of course, you're still going to lose some information if you (say) divide by 3... but that's much easier for everyone to understand (and probably decide policy around) as we're all used to decimal arithmetic. Generally speaking, naturally-imprecise quantities such as height and weight are good for double; exact, manmade quantities are good for decimal.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326763(v=vs.71).aspx has a great double to decimal .Net code example that should help you avoid edge cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you round to 2dp, IMO the "right" way would be store an integer that is the multiple - i.e. for 12.34 you store the integer 1234. No more double rounding woe.

If you **must** use double, this still works; all integers are guaranteed to be stored exactly in double - so still use the same trick.

Comment: Wouldn't storing double as int considered premature optimization?  1. You will to remember to do conversions in view, updates, and saves.  2. If the business requirement changes, then you are in big trouble? What if finance department later wants 4 decimal places?

Comment: also, you are reducing the maximum/minimum number by 2 digits for using this.  So, instead of +/- 2Billions, you now have only +/- 20 millions.  Yes, you could use Int64, but what's the point now?

Comment: @Holystream: By "integer" I don't think he means `Int32`; I think he means "whole numbers".  Many older systems did not support `Int64` or `Decimal`, but did support `Double`, which can accommodate, without loss of precision, all whole numbers up to 4,503,599,627,370,496 (or, scaling by a factor of 100, all penny amounts up to $45,035,996,273,704.96)